# Clampled cubic splines with flat extrapolation

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, extrapolation, cubic-spline

I am trying to implement a clamped cubic spline with a zero slope (flat extrapolation) at the boundary knots, but I am unable to obtain the desired results.

For instance setting:

```
x = [3 4 7 9];
y = [2 1 2 0.5];
```

I can use the CSAPE function to obtain the piecewise polynomial

```
pp = csape(x,y,'variational');
```

Next, evaluating the pp in the range [0-10] yields,

```
xx = 0:0.1:10;
yy =ppval(pp,xx);
plot(xx,yy)
```

[image]

However, this method do not achieve a flat extrapolation outside the [3-9] range (i.e for x<3 all values for y should be 2, and for x>9 all values for y should be 0.5)

Is there any way to achieve the desired result?

**Edit:** Continuity at the boundary knot should be preserved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's any need to use `csape`, you can just use `spline`. From the documentation for `spline`:

> If Y is a vector that contains two more values than x has entries, the
>   first and last value in Y are used as the endslopes for the cubic
>   spline.

Also, spline allows you to obtain the interpolated `yy` values directly, so:

```
x = [3 4 7 9];
y = [2 1 2 0.5];
xx = 0:0.1:10;
yy = spline(x,[0 y 0], xx);
plot(xx,yy)
```

This gives me the plot below.

[image: Spline Plot]

Looking at this, the slope is zero at the boundaries (x=3 and x=9), which is what we are asking of a 'clamped' spline with zero gradient at the boundaries. If you wish to have zero gradient beyond the boundaries, I would recommend just doing the following:

```
yy(xx<x(1)) = y(1);
yy(xx>x(length(x))) = y(length(y));
```

Giving:

[image]

**Edit**

This gives a continuous `y` function at the end-knots, but `y'` is not smooth at the end-knots. If you would like `y`' to be smooth you could pad your input arrays and use this as the input to your `spline` function. This would give you some oscillations as shown below, though, which may or may not be what you want.

```
% Spline on padded input arrays
x = [0 1 2 3 4 7 9 10 11 12];
y = [2 2 2 2 1 2 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5];
yy = spline(x,y, xx);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you RPM. This is very useful. Indeed what I need is to have a zero gradient beyond the boundaries, as in the second plot. Just one additional question: do the substitution of the values outside the boundaries by y(1) and y(length(y)) preserve the continuity of the function at the boundary knots?

Comment: Well, just looking at the plot, you can see `y` is continuous, but I don't think `y'` will be smooth. If you do want these to be smooth, you could pad your arrays (add `2`s to the beginning and `0.5`s to the end in your case), but you will then find that the curve oscillates instead of being flat. I'll make an edit to this effect.